# MATLAB - Changepoint analysis or "findchangepts": How does it work?

Tags: matlab

I am using the function findchangepts and use 'linear' which detects changes in mean and slope. How does it note a change? Is it by consecutive points until the next point has a different mean and slope?
Mathworks has the following explanation:

If x is a vector with N elements, then findchangepts partitions x into two regions, x(1:ipt-1) and x(ipt:N), that minimize the sum of the residual (squared) error of each region from its local mean.

How does the function get ipt?
Thanks in advance!
I am working with a single vector with N elements.

Comment: Take `ipt = 1`, you will have a sum of residuals `r(1)`. Now take `ipt = 2`, you will have a sum of residuals `r(2)`, and so on until `r(N)`. Where's the minimum of `r`? That's the value that function takes as `ipt`.

Comment: Thank you, Matteo V. But for it to do sum of residuals, does it not need an estimate to compare the value to? This is part of my confusion, what does it consider an empirical estimate?

Comment: As written in the part of the documentation that you reported, the sum of the residuals is taken with respect to the local mean of the subset. So if we go back to my simple explanation, the residuals for `ipt = i` with `i = 1,...,N` are (probably) equal to something like `r(i) = sqrt(sum((x(1:ipt) - mean(x(1:ipt)).^2) + sum((x(ipt+1:N) - mean(x(ipt+1:N)).^2));`. At least that's what I get from the documentation, I haven't really checked how it is implemented in Matlab.